# Magento admin error: Image file was not found

Tags: product, admin, magento-1, error, image

I have a custom module with two controllers, one for admin and one for frontend:
http://dev.magento18.com/admin/example_myadmincontroller/preview/id/2/ 
http://dev.magento18.com/example/mycontroller/?id=1&storeId=1

```
mycontrollerAction(){
  $html = Mage::helper('mymodule/helpername')->myHelperFunction();
  ...
}

myadmincontrollerAction(){
  $html = Mage::helper('mymodule/helpername')->myHelperFunction();
  ...
}
```

Both controllers call the same helper. Inside helper I do:

```
myHelperFunction(){
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1);
  //if product doesn't have image it will display placeholder on frontend, 
  //in backend triggers error Image file was not found.
  $imgSrc = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
  ...
  return $html
}
```

If product doesn't have image, it will display placeholder on frontend. But in backend the same helper triggers error `Image file was not found.`. Has anybody had the same issue, how could I pass this error and make it display placeholder also in admin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I came out with this simple solution:

```
try{
  $imgSrc = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  $imgSrc = Mage::getDesign()->getSkinUrl('images/catalog/product/placeholder/image.jpg',array('_area'=>'frontend'));  
}
```

Answer (score 10):

try this i hade the same issue and works

Go to admin > System > Configuration > Catalog > Product Image Placeholders

and upload some Image Place Holders…

Answer (score 3):

```
There are 2 ways to solve this.

   1) You can upload your product placeholder images at 
         System->Configuration->Catalog->Product Image Placeholders
   2) If you want to use magento's default placeholders then
      go to 
          skin/frontend/base/default/images Or
          skin/frontend/default/default/images/
and copy the **catalog** folder and paste that folder to 
          skin/adminhtml/base/default/images/
```

## **Update 1:**

For your Custom module follow following steps
1) you can create folder for placeholder images at

```
  media/mymodule/placeholder/placeholderImage.jpg
```

2) re-Write model Class

```
 Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image
```

3) Update the method

```
  public function setBaseFile($file)
```

Line around at **304**

```
$baseFile = $baseDir . $file;

        if ((!$file) || (!file_exists($baseFile))) {
            throw new Exception(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image file was not found.'));
        }
```

replace with

```
$baseFile = $baseDir . $file;

    if ((!$file) || (!file_exists($baseFile))) {
        $module = $this->getRequest()->getModuleName();
        if($module=='mymodule'){
          $baseFile = Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'mymodule/placeholder/placeholderImage.jpg';
        }else{
          throw new Exception(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Image file was not found.'));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tnx but none of the ways are ok for me. I am making a module which will be used by others. I can not say them to upload placeholder images. I also can not copy the catalog folders because if it was already copied it will make error during installation and leave the site maintenance mode.

Comment: Please check updated answer may b that help you solve the problem.Please let me know if any Query.

Comment: Why this rewrite, I think it would be better to simple use try catch block (see my answer I just submited).

Comment: yes, that is better solution. thank you. can use in future.

Answer (score 1):

I was needed to developed a extension and get the base_image to be more performance the flow and send information.
I got the same issue, BTW, @Namita very good explication about the issue and how to fix it.

So here is a solution without any re-write class, I just created a new function checking if I'm in admin or not.

```
public function getProductImagePath($product){

    $isAdmin        = Mage::app()->getStore()->isAdmin();
    $imageHelper    = Mage::helper('catalog/image');

    if($isAdmin){
        $currentArea    = Mage::getDesign()->getArea();
        Mage::getDesign()->setArea(Mage_Core_Model_Design_Package::DEFAULT_AREA);
    }

    $image = $imageHelper->init($product,'small_image')->resize(135)->__toString();

    if($isAdmin){
        Mage::getDesign()->setArea($currentArea);
    }

    return $image;
}
```

Hope this solution help.

Best,
Alejandro.