# Exception printing enabled but now I can't sort the issue! HELP!

Tags: error-log

I have a problem with Magento.

Everything was working fine but today I noticed that when I try to click a link on a certain page Magento gives me the exception printing warning.

I modified the local.xml.sample to local.xml to see what was the problem but...I don't really know, I can't understand what is the problem.

I try to copy the log here, PLEASE HELP!!!

```
"
Image file was not found.

Trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Image.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Image->setBaseFile('/s/t/stv_007_2....')
#1 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion6/template/catalog/product/list.phtml(176): Mage_Catalog_Helper_Image->init(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product), 'rotator_image')
#2 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_list', true)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Category/View.php(90): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_list')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml(70): Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View->getProductListHtml()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#12 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#17 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#18 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/design/frontend/default/ma_sahara_fashion6/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(59): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#19 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#20 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/defaul...')
#21 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#23 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/local/Magentothem/Layerednavigationajax/controllers/CategoryController.php(127): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Magentothem_Layerednavigationajax_CategoryController->viewAction()
#27 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#28 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#29 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#31 /var/www/vhosts/shirtsandtiesvenice.co.uk/httpdocs/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#32 {main}
"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that image that is tried to set to a product doesn't exist or invalid path is given. Have you been removing some files from your server recently?

You didn't give too much information about where and when it happens, but maybe you'll find the answer here: [Magento admin error: Image file was not found](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/35044/magento-admin-error-image-file-was-not-found)